# What to return from a function with reference return type?

Tags: c++, function

```
className &temp (someOtherclassName &c)
```

The question is what should I return I am trying to return just an object that is newly created in the class, it's not working, I also tried returning reference or pointer, and it's not working.

```
Klub &novKlub(Clen &c){
    Klub newKlub;
    strcpy(newKlub.name, name);

    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        if(c.getLevel() == clenovi->getLevel()){
            newKlub += clenovi[i];

        }

    }
    return newKlub;
}
```

---

Here's all the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class Clen{
private:
char name[50];
char surname[50];
int level;
public:
Clen(char n[] = "null", char s[] = "null", int l = 1){
    strcpy(name, n);
    strcpy(surname, s);
    level = l;
}

//operator++
Clen operator++(int){
    Clen temp(*this);
    ++level;
    return temp;
}

//++operator
Clen &operator ++ (){
    ++level;

    return *this;
}

int getLevel(){
    return level;
}

//operator <<
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const Clen &right);

//operator==
friend bool operator == (const Clen &left, const Clen &right);

//operator!=
friend bool operator != (const Clen &left, const Clen &right);

};
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const Clen &right){
output << right.name << " " << right.surname << ", " << right.level << endl;
return output;
}

bool operator == (const Clen &left, const Clen &right){
if(left.level == right.level)
    return true;

return false;
}

bool operator != (const Clen &left, const Clen &right){
return !(left == right);
}

class Klub{
private:
char name[100];
Clen *clenovi;
int elements;
void copy(const Klub &toCopy){
    strcpy(name, toCopy.name);
    elements = toCopy.elements;

    clenovi = new Clen[elements + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        clenovi[i] = toCopy.clenovi[i];
    }
}

public:
//constructor
Klub(char n[] = "null", Clen c[] = NULL, int e = 0){
    strcpy(name, n);
    elements = e;

    clenovi = new Clen[elements + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        clenovi[i] = c[i];
    }
}
//copy constructor
Klub(const Klub &toCopy){
    copy(toCopy);
}

//assignment operator
Klub &operator = (const Klub &right){
    if(this == &right)
        return *this;
    delete [] clenovi;
    copy(right);

    return *this;
}

//destructor
~Klub(){
    delete [] clenovi;
}

//operator <<
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const Klub &right);


//operator +=
Klub &operator +=(Clen c){
    Clen *temp = clenovi;
    clenovi = new Clen[elements + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        clenovi[i] = temp[i];

    }

    clenovi[elements] = c;
    ++elements;
    delete [] temp;
    return *this;

}

Klub &novKlub(Clen &c){
    Klub newKlub;
    strcpy(newKlub.name, name);

    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        if(c.getLevel() == clenovi->getLevel()){
            newKlub += clenovi[i];

        }

    }
    return *this;
}
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const Klub &right){
output << right.name << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < right.elements; i++){
    output << right.clenovi[i] << endl;
}

return output;
}
int main()
{
Clen clen;
int n, stepen;
char ime[30], prezime[30];
cin >> ime >> n;
Klub k1(ime); 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> ime >> prezime >> stepen;
    Clen c(ime, prezime, stepen);
    k1 += c;
    clen = c; 
}  
Klub k2 = k1.novKlub(clen);
cout << k2;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what the function is supposed to do. Usually, you return the instance the function is being called on, or one of the arguments (which is also a reference). You can't return by reference anything created within the function. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @101010 I should return the newly created temporary object from the function.

Comment: @M.T No! That is the one thing you should definitely *not* do. You will end up with a reference to something that no longer exists.

Comment: returning a **temporary** object by reference is not a good idea.

Comment: You shouldn't return a reference at all here; just return by value.

Comment: The idea behind this is that we have a Club(Klub) with many members, and in this function we should create a newKlub that will have members of the same level and this is how we later call the function: Klub k2 = k1.novKlub(clen);

Comment: *Don’t* return a reference, return a value. It’s as simple as that. What made you think that you should return a reference here?

Comment: @KonradRudolpf it's not working.

Comment: @M.T What do you mean by “it’s not working”? Be specific.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it's not returning what it should.

Comment: Well, given the use of `strcpy(newKlub.name, name)` outside of the constructor, the `Klub` class is probably completely broken anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You should return your object by value, not reference. Change your declaration to:

```
Klub novKlub(Clen &c)
```

Functions should never return a reference to a local object, as it is destroyed upon function return leaving a dangling reference.

**UPDATE:** If changing the signature is not an option, you should still not return a reference to a local. In this case, presumably the intention is to create the object which is inserted into some container, and then return a reference to it within this container. You haven't provided enough detail about your classes to say exactly what this could be, but perhaps it shoud be inserted into `clenovi` or `c`. If you provide more detail for those this can be clarified.

Comment: Well, the thing is this is an assignment from my OOP course, and I am not supposed to change the function, it should be done with this prototype: Klub &novKlub(Clen &c)

Comment: With this function a new Klub is created that contains all the members that have the same level as c (the argument). -> the instruction

Comment: As the code stands it doesn't make any sense to return the new `Klub` by reference. For this to be possible the function `novKlub` must have access to some sort of container or other external object holder to which it can add the new instance. I don't see such a thing in your code.

Comment: what do you mean by some sort of container or other external object holder?

Comment: Suppose you had a class static (or even global) variable `std::vector<Klub>`. Then, if in `novKlub` you inserted your new element into this container, then there would be nothing wrong with returning a reference to this newly-inserted element within the container as it would no longer be a function-local object

Comment: we're not supposed to use vector :(

Comment: That was just an example. You can use any other container or even set the new object as a property on some other external object type, not even necessarily a container. The key is it must not be just a function-local object.

Answer (score 5):

Given that you are creating a new object, return it by value.

Situations that call for returning a reference are somewhat limited (see below). Your situation is not one of them.

> The question is what should I return [if I want to return a reference]

You should return an object with static lifetime, or lifetime known to the caller. Make sure that the caller does not need to free your object.

> I am trying to return just an object that is newly created in the class, it's not working

You should not require the caller to free objects that you return by reference, so returning a newly created object is not an option.

> I also tried returning reference or pointer, and it's not working.

You need to return an object that does not go out of scope upon return. Usually you want to return

- Your object itself, i.e. `*this`, or
- One of your object's dependents, i.e. `this->someField`, or
- One of your function parameters (this is a very common pattern in `<<` overriding), or
- A static or global variable (not recommended).